# Is this lie algebra isomorphic to $\mathfrak{sl}(2,\mathbb R)$?

Tags: matrices, lie-groups, lie-algebras

I have a lie group $G$, its (real? it was never mentioned in the text/context) lie algebra $\mathfrak {g}$ and three linear independent (over $\mathbb {R}$, but also over $\mathbb {C}$) elements $x,y,z\in \mathfrak{g}$ such that $[x,y]=az, [z,x]=bx, [z,y]=-by$ for constants $a<0<b$.

Is the lie subalgebra generated by $x,y,z$ isomorphic to $\mathfrak{sl}(2,\mathbb R)$?

It seems very similar. I want to take $u=\lambda x, v=\lambda y, w=\mu z$ and say that for a suitable $\lambda, \mu$ those elements satisfy the relations of $\mathfrak{sl}(2,\mathbb R)$. Indeed, if we demand $[u,v]=w, [w,u]=2u, [w,v]=-2v$ we get the equations $\lambda^2a=\mu, \lambda\mu b=2\lambda$ which turn as $\mu=\frac{2}{b}, \lambda^2=\frac{2}{ab}<0$. So if I would allow imaginary constants, I'm done. Problem is I'm not certain that this is allowed (or to be accurate, I'm pretty sure I am not). Yet, even if I'm not allowed, this doesn't prove that they are **not** isomorphic.

Any comments or different approaches are welcome.

Comment: Oh, here's the problem. Structural constants of $\mathfrak{sl}_2$ are not like that. It should either be $[w,u] = -2u$, $[w,v] = 2v$, or $[w,u] = 2u$, $[w,v] = -2v$.

Comment: The reason I tend to not allow imaginary constants is that to the best of my understanding $\mathfrak{g}$ might not include the element $ix$ for instance, as it is just a real (?) vector space.
Regarding the structural constants, you are of course right, but it's merely a typo in my attempted solution and does not change the contradiction I'm getting, as the equations stand still.
 @Ennar

Comment: Yes, but in practice you might be located in $M_2(\mathbb C)$ or something similar, depending on the context. For example, you might be studying real lie group, look at its real lie algebra and consider complexification of it. On the other hand, you might be considering complex lie algebra and look at its so called real form, i.e. real lie algebra $\mathfrak g_0$ inside complex lie algebra $\mathfrak g$ such that complexification of $\mathfrak g_0$ is $\mathfrak g$.

Comment: To prove they're not isomorphic as real Lie algebras (though, as you say, they are isomorphic when complexified), you could hope that the signatures of the Killing forms are different.

Comment: Just let $v = - \lambda y$.

Comment: @Ennar: This cannot work, as the equation for the second relation would be $\lambda\mu b=2\lambda$ and the for the third equation (which wasn't shown in my attempted solution as it is identical to the second) will be $\lambda\mu b=-2\lambda$ if im not mistaken

Comment: @paulgarrett: What I'm really interested in is showing that the connected lie subgroup corresponding to $\langle x,y,z\rangle$ is locally isomorphic to $SL(2,\mathbb R)$ (which is true for sure if the lie algebras are isomorphic). I suppose then that isomorphism as complex lie groups would suffice. Are the lie algebras also complex lie algebras in a straightforward manner or does a complexification (@Ennar) necessary? In the latter case, would it still preserve the local isomorphism I'm looking for?

Comment: @The way of life, no, if you let $v' = -v$ and you have $[w,v] = \alpha v$, then $[w,v'] = [w,-v] = -[w,v] = -\alpha v = \alpha(-v) = \alpha v'$ as well. I mean, you could just say that eigenvectors form subspace. Hence, changing the sign of $v$ only upsets $[u,v]$, but that is what we want.

Comment: @Ennar: Oh, that's quite simple of me. I think it simply works :)

Still, the complexification issues I was mentioning in my last comment interests me so anyone is welcome to pitch in. Is it best to open a new question, or keep the discussion here?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you change $v = -\lambda y$, then you get the following:

$$[u,v]=[\lambda x,-\lambda y] = -\lambda^2[x,y] = -\lambda^2az = -\frac{\lambda^2 a}{\mu}w$$

$$[w,u]=[\mu z,\lambda x] = \mu\lambda[z,x] = \mu\lambda bx = \mu b u$$

$$[w,v]=[\mu z,-\lambda y] = -\mu\lambda[z,y] = -\mu\lambda (-by) = -\mu b v$$

and thus, let $\mu = \frac 2b$, $\lambda = \sqrt{-\frac 2{ab}}$.

Answer (score 2):

Responding to the continuation of the question in the comments: up to isomorphism, there are two real Lie algebras whose complexifications are (isomorphic to) $\mathfrak{sl}(2,\mathbb R)$ and $\mathfrak{su}(2)$, attached to real Lie groups $SL_2(\mathbb R)$ and $SU(2)$. On the former, the Killing form has indefinite signature, but on the latter the Killing form is definite.

The problem (in your comment and in @Ennar's answer) of needing to take a square root of a negative number to put your Lie algebra in isomorphism with $\mathfrak{sl}(2,\mathbb R)$ strongly suggests to me (without computing anything) that your Lie algebra is isomorphic to $\mathfrak{su}(2)$, not $\mathfrak{sl}(2,\mathbb R)$. Yes, their complexifications are isomorphic, but this certainly does not imply that the real Lie groups are locally isomorphic.

Answer (score 1):

I think that your line of argument is slightly too complicated. If you first define $\tilde z=(2/b)z$, then you have $[\tilde z,x]=2x$ and $[\tilde z,y]=-2y$. These just mean that $x$ and $y$ are eigenvectors for $ad(z)$, so they remain the same if you multiply $x$ and/or $y$ by any non-zero factor. The third relation is $[x,y]=az=(ab/2)\tilde z$, so if you put $\tilde x=(2/ab)x$, then $\tilde x$, $y$, and $\tilde z$ form a standard $\mathfrak{sl}_2$-basis.